# Magento 2: How to call PHP file in another phtml file inside the module?

Tags: magento2.3.4, blog, customization

I am using [magefan blog extension](https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension#live-demo), i want to move [post page bottom section related product](https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension#live-demo) to sidebar

[image]

I have created custom phtml file based on the side bar postion under app\code\Magefan\Blog\view\frontend\templates\sidebar\related_products.phtml

```
<?php 
echo "hell hello";
?>
```

The output,

[image]

The related product php file under \app\code\Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\View\RelatedProducts.php how to call this file into side bar section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do this via XML.

In **app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magefan_Blog/layout/blog_post_view.xml**

add:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="blog.post.relatedproducts" destination="blog.sidebar" after="blog.sidebar.search"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: FYI i am using extension, file under app/code/magefan/blog. How to update here, if i wrong pls correct me

Comment: You will need to override the extension code within your own theme as per Magento 2 best-practices. Create the xml file in the path stated above and paste the above snippet, clear the cache and it should work.

Comment: Thank you its working.

Comment: I did move element in my module xml file, its working.

Answer (score 1):

To call a block file in phtml, you can do like this.

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\View\RelatedProducts');
echo $blockObj->getAnyMethod();
?>
```

Comment: The link is not working

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the link broken, thanks you for your effort..